# How to use sub query in group by clause sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

my table data as follows

```
FinishDate                  SpecialistName  jobstate
-----------------------     --------------- ---------
2012-10-01 00:00:00.000     Josh            FINISHED
2012-10-01 00:00:00.000     Josh            FINISHED
2012-10-01 00:00:00.000     Sam             FINISHED
2012-10-01 00:00:00.000     Robin           FINISHED
2012-10-01 00:00:00.000     Robin           FINISHED
2012-10-01 00:00:00.000     Joy             FINISHED
2012-10-01 00:00:00.000     Joy             INCOMMING
2012-10-02 00:00:00.000     Joy             FINISHED
```

my query as follows

```
select Count(*) [Count] from employee
where convert(varchar,FinishDate,112)>='20121001' 
and convert(varchar,FinishDate,112) <='20121001'  
and JobState='FINISHED'
group by SpecialistName
```

if a particular specialist finish multiple jobs in same day then i want to show 1

if robin,josh & Sam finish 10 jobs in same day then 3 will be shown for that day

then output will be like

```
FinishDate                  Count
-----------------------     ------
2012-10-01 00:00:00.000     3     
2012-10-02 00:00:00.000     5
2012-10-03 00:00:00.000     15
```

so just guide me how to customize my sql to have desire result. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something along these lines. Syntax may not be perfect (did "freehand")

```
Select 
  TheDate
, Count(*) [Count]
From
(
    select 
      convert(varchar,FinishDate,112) TheDate
    , SpecialistName
    from employee
    where convert(varchar,FinishDate,112)>='20121001' 
    and convert(varchar,FinishDate,112) <='20121001'  
    and JobState='FINISHED'
    group by 
      convert(varchar,FinishDate,112)
    , SpecialistName
) t1    
Group By 
  TheDate
```

It has to be two selects because the groupings that you want are different. If you did a single select grouping by FinishDate and SpecialistName what you would get would be a count of the distinct *combinations* of those two.

What you want is to get the distinct SpecialistNames that had at least one entry in a date. Distinct because you care that they had an entry, but not whether they had 1 or 3 or 17. This is done by the inner query.

*Then* you want to take these distinct SpecialistName with corresponding date and summarize them by FinishDate to get a count of specialists by date. This is done by the outer query.

Part of your comment mentions Distinct and you could in fact use Select Distinct instead of Group By in the inner query since we don’t need a count there. The outer query does require the Group By since you do need a count. My own bias is to use group by rather than distinct in case I need an aggregate function later, but that’s me. It would be perfectly OK to use Select Distinct if you prefer.

Comment: can we specify select statement in group by clause. like group by (select distinct SpecialistName from employee) if this is not possible then please help me to understand the reason. thanks

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question, but let me amend answer and see if it helps. See edits.